# When was the first occurrence of the bleeping sound when letters appear on the screen?

Tags: sound-effects

Oftentimes during TV shows, when a location or a character is introduced, there is a bleeping, digital noise each time a letter appears on the screen.
[image: Spy game: text showing where the current action is located]
I have seen this mostly in cop chase shows when presenting people in a "hero" kind of way, or in movies when the current location is described by a text at the bottom of the screen.

Example from a TV show:

Example from a movie:

When was this sound effect used for the first time in the context of introducing a character or a location to the viewer?

Comment: Can you link to some scenes with examples?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Joachim. I added an example. I'm sure that there are thousands of them, but I'm not sure about the keywords to search for

Comment: The ancestor of this effect is probably showing some flavor teletype, with headlines or other vital information printed onto a strip or sheet of paper with mechanical noise in the background, as in the intro to the 1970 British TV show "U.F.O."

Comment: This is nothing!